# Scheme Error Unknown Identifier: map when using higher order function

Tags: scheme, higher-order-functions

Essentially, I am trying to write a scheme method which will use the map function to cube every item in a list. so it would go from '(1 2 3 4) to '(1 8 27 64). Here is my current code:

```
(define (cube-all lst) 
  (map (lambda (x) (* (* x x) x)) lst)
)
```

This is the error message:

```
SchemeError: unknown identifier: map

Current Eval Stack:
-------------------------
0: map
1: (cube-all (quote (1 2 3 4)))
2: (println (cube-all (quote (1 2 3 4))))
```

Is this due to improper syntax? Or do I have to do something else with map?

Edit: println is another function which just displays the answer

Comment: What Scheme interpreter / version are you using? `map` should be generally available in most Schemes.

Comment: how do you call the code ?

Comment: Error message appears to come from [this "Scheme interpreter"](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61a/fa14/assets/interpreter/scheme.html). Consider using [DrRacket](https://racket-lang.org)

Comment: @mnemenaut I guess that is a R4RS standard Scheme and it does not have `map`.  I guess OP should use a Scheme implementation 18 years old R5RS or newer to get fancy "new" functionality like `map`.

Comment: @ohararj123, @Sylwester: "R0RS" (the original Scheme report, 1975) had `AMAPLIST` (from Lisp 1.5); in R1RS (1978) it's described as a "standard system-provided extension"; in R2RS (1985) it's called `map` and described as an "essential procedure", with the note "it is guaranteed that every implementation of Scheme will support the essential ... procedures". It's unfortunate for an interpreter lacking `map` to call itself "Scheme".

Comment: @ohararj123 I knew of `maplist`, but didn't find `map` in R3RS but I must have gone through too fast. A lot of implementations call themselves Scheme without conforming to a report fully. It's a disgrace with the language being so small ti begin with.

Answer (score 1):

If you are constrained to using [the 'scheme' mentioned in a comment](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61a/fa14/assets/interpreter/scheme.html) then you can't use `map`.

But ... you can *write* `map`:

```
(define (reverse l)
  (define (reverse-loop lt into)
    (if (null? lt)
        into
        (reverse-loop (cdr lt) (cons (car lt) into))))
  (reverse-loop l '()))

(define (map f l)
  (define (map-loop lt into)
    (if (null? lt)
        (reverse into)
        (map-loop (cdr lt) (cons (f (car lt)) into))))
  (map-loop l '()))

(define (cube-all lst) 
  (map (lambda (x) (* (* x x) x)) lst))

(cube-all '(1 2 3))
```